FiX Url from Alertamanager email messages
I'm installing alertmanager , when I get an notification, the url is wrong, I'm using https instead http , when I click on url button or link , it goes for Http. there is anyway to resolve that? how can i fix?
http error
alertamanger message
I tried to check on alertmanager.yml if I have something to edit.
alertmanager.yml
global:
  smtp_smarthost: 'mail.company.eu'  # Add your SMTP server here
  smtp_from: 'alertmanager@company.eu'       # Add the sender email address here
  smtp_require_tls: false

route:
  group_by: ['alertname']
  group_wait: 30s
  group_interval: 1m
  repeat_interval: 10m
  receiver: 'email-notifications'
  routes:
    - match:
        severity: 'critical'
      receiver: 'email-notifications'
      mute_time_intervals: ['sunday']  # Mute critical alerts during specified times
    - match:
        severity: 'warning'
      receiver: 'null-receiver'

receivers:
  - name: 'email-notifications'
    email_configs:
      - to: 'teams.company1.onmicrosoft.com@amer.teams.ms'  # Add the receiver email address here
        send_resolved: true
  - name: 'null-receiver'

inhibit_rules:
  - source_match:
      severity: 'critical'
    target_match:
      severity: 'warning'
    equal: ['alertname', 'dev', 'instance']

time_intervals:
  - name: 'sunday'
    time_intervals:
      - times:
          - start_time: '00:00'
            end_time: '22:00'
        weekdays: ['sunday']

web-config.yml
tls_server_config:
    cert_file: C:\certificate\certificate.pem
    key_file: C:\certificate\private_key.pem
basic_auth_users:
    admin: XXXXXX


This is not set in configs, but rather in command line option --web.external-url: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47885588/21363224
